# Некорректные символы после архивирования файла

Tags: java, кодировка

Исходный файл в UTF-8. Нужно создать zip-архив. Архивирую так:

```
FileInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\input.xml");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
FileOutputStream baos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\output.xml");
ZipArchiveOutputStream zos = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(baos);
ZipArchiveEntry ze = new ZipArchiveEntry(fileName);
zos.putArchiveEntry(ze);
InputStream in = byteArrayInputStream;
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
in.close();
zos.closeArchiveEntry();
zos.close();
baos.close();
byteArrayInputStream.close();
```

При открытии заархивированного xml в текстовом редакторе (например notepad++) открывается некорректное содержимое, например: 
`<Вх_ВЗЛ:xd0?сточникДанных>ЗЛ</Вх_ВЗЛ:xd0?сточникДанных>`
т.е. вместо "И" непонятные символы

Как это исправить

Comment: `ZipArchiveOutputStream` создает .zip-файл, т.е. архив (его можно проводником или архиватором открыть), содержащий файл `ZipArchiveEntry` (с именем из `fileName`), не очень понятно, почему вы его сохраняете, как .xml, и как потом открываете. `D0`- первый байт "И" в utf-8, второй байт там `98`. Исходный файл нормальный? Ощущение, что кто-то читает файл блоками по N байт, перекодирует блок, и клеит результаты, поэтому когда многобайтный символ попадает на границу блоков, получается фигня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вопрос решился при таком коде, т.е. без принудительной установки UTF-8

```
zos.setFallbackToUTF8(true); 
zos.setUseLanguageEncodingFlag(true); 
zos.setCreateUnicodeExtraFields(ZipArchiveOutputStream.UnicodeExtraFieldPolicy.ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
zos.setEncoding("UTF-8");
zos.setFallbackToUTF8(true); // для неизвестных симовлов
zos.setUseLanguageEncodingFlag(true);                               
zos.setCreateUnicodeExtraFields(ZipArchiveOutputStream.UnicodeExtraFieldPolicy.ALWAYS);
```

Comment: не помогло. результат такой же

Comment: какая кодировка в результате отображается?